# How do I fix my code for blocking showing/hiding menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got problem with pause menu holding esc key fix.

I writed simple script that blocks showing/hiding pause menu for 5 seconds, but it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or fix my code?

(Here I'm writing cuz i cant post my question lol)

**Here is code:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool IsGamePaused = false;
    public static bool IsClickingBlocked = false;

    public GameObject zagadka1;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T))
        {
            if (IsGamePaused)
            {
                if (IsClickingBlocked == false) { 
                    ClickStopCounter();
                    zagadka1Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (IsClickingBlocked == false)
                {
                    zagadka1Stop();
                    ClickStopCounter();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ClickStopCounter()
    {
        IsClickingBlocked = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        IsClickingBlocked = false;
    }
    public void zagadka1Start()
    {
        zagadka1.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        IsGamePaused = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    void zagadka1Stop()
    {
        zagadka1.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        IsGamePaused = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use StartCoroutine when calling the Coroutine.

Try this one. StartCoroutine(ClickStopCounter())